# How to read a file even after closing the handle in Windows?

Tags: winapi, dropbox

I need to read a file in Windows and avoid any OS-level locks so users can delete the file even while my application is reading from it.

Using typical read operations via C++, Python, Java, etc reveal the same expected sequence of Winapi calls when evaluated through procmon:

1. CreateFile
2. ReadFile (multiple times until "END OF FILE" is reached)
3. CloseFile

If I try to delete the file via Explorer between steps 1 and 3 (basically after CreateFile and before CloseFile), I'll get a "file in use" error.

However, I noticed that when Dropbox reads files to upload to the server, the sequence is:

1. CreateFile
2. CloseFile
3. ReadFile
4. Repeat steps 1-3

Since ReadFile is called after CloseFile, I can still delete the file even while Dropbox is reading it.

I can't figure out how Winapi allows for ReadFile after CloseFile is called.

I've attached a screenshot of Procmon that shows Dropbox's behavior.

Anybody know how this is done?

[image: Procmon showing Dropbox]

Comment: Calling CreateFile more than once is valid, just count them.  Count up on CreateFile, down on CloseHandle.  The CloseHandle just after the reads is the one that truly destroyed the last handle and pairs with the first CreateFile in the screenshot.  So your assumption is just not valid.

Comment: :( You're right ... I feel dumb. Thanks @HansPassant :)

Comment: you can use opportunistic lock (oplock) on the file, say FSCTL_REQUEST_OPLOCK for be notify when oplock is broken (for close file handle) - read more - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365433(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RemyLebeau - file will be not actually deleted until you not close it handle, and read not return error even after other call delete on file

Answer (score 1):

This create-close-read semantics should be caused by the fact that the file is mapped to a memory region in application's address space. When the application attempts to read from that region, the operating system reads necessary data from the file and delivers them to the application (the data appear in the memory region where the file is mapped).

Memory mapped files are backed by a file mapping objects (called a section in the kernel world). Given a file handle, you can create such an object via `CreateFileMapping` and map it to your address space through `MapViewOfFile` (some Ex variants also exist). The file mapping object keeps an extra reference to the file it maps. So, after creating the file mapping object for a file, you can close the file handle and read the file through the file mapping object.